# How Can I move the "Proceed to Checkout" button outside of the cart block?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout

So when you click on a product, you get taken to the cart page, in my layouts I have a sidebar included before the content, so i can get a two column layout.

I want the proceed to checkout button to be in the sidebar and not the content area with all the products, buttons etc..

This is what my sidebar include/block looks like:

```
<aside class="checkout-process">    
   <div class="totals">     
       <?
           echo $this->getChildHtml('totals');

           if(!$this->hasError())
           {                
               ?>
                   <ul class="checkout-types">
                       <?
                           foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method)
                           {
                               if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method))
                               {
                                   ?>
                                       <li><?= $methodHtml; ?></li>
                                   <? 
                               }
                           } 
                       ?>
                  </ul>
              <?
            }
        ?>      
    </div>
</aside>
```

However When I tried this, i got an error saying that

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /httpdocs/app/design/frontend/choice/default/template/page/html/checkout_process.phtml on line 12
```

I've spend the past 3 hours searching through google and stack overflow, but i've come up dry, could anyone explain what i need to do to move this button into another block? or direct me to a tutorial that will help?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new instance of `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart` as e.g. `custom_methods`, assign that as the child of your column parent (e.g. "right"), and then set the `checkout.cart.top_methods` block as a child of your block:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="right">
        <block name="custom_methods" type="checkout/cart" template="custom/template.phtml" >
            <action method="insert">
                <block>checkout.cart.top_methods</block>
                <sib></sib>
                <after />
                <alias>myMethodDisplay</alias>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Then in your *`custom/template.phtml`*, do the following:

```
<div class="page-title title-buttons">
    <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
    <ul class="checkout-types">
    <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('myMethodDisplay') as $method): ?>
        <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
        <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get checkout link in any template file like this:

```
$checkout_link = Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl();
```

Now just put it anywhere you like:

```
<a href="<?php echo $checkout_link ?>">Proceed to Checkout</a>
```

The function itself is located at `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper\Url.php`
Same way you can call any other function from that file, if you might need for example multishipping link then just call getMSCheckoutUrl()

```
<?php $multishipping_checkout = Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getMSCheckoutUrl(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $multishipping_checkout ?>">Multishipping</a>
```

and so forth..

Answer (score 0):

$this->getMethods('top_methods') in checkout/cart.phtml runs the following code:

```
public function getMethods($nameInLayout)
{
    if ($this->getChild($nameInLayout) instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
        return $this->getChild($nameInLayout)->getSortedChildren();
    }
    return array();
}
```

This is method of Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart. But if you use $this->getMethods('top_methods') in other block then Magento run native getter "$this->getData('methods')" which return NULL in your case.

Solution for displaying only "Place Checkout" button:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl() ?>">
    <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Proceed to Checkout');?>
</a>
```

Comment: could you suggest a solution? Is there a way to allow other blocks access to this function?

Comment: If you need only "Place Checkout" button without "Checkout with Multiple Addresses" link then put it in your template:

`<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl() ?>"><?php Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Proceed to Checkout');?></a>`

Comment: I do not see any reason for this: `<?php Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Proceed to Checkout');?>` and it also does nothing. You at least have to echo it, to have any effect at all, but the correct way, would be just this: `<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl() ?>"><?php $this->__('Proceed to Checkout');?></a>`

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you forgot "echo", too :) And you can not use $this instead of Mage::helper('checkout') because 'Mage_Checkout' module has translation for string "Proceed to Checkout" and $this would work only if block is part of "Mage_Checkout" module.